# How to combine two or more related but distinct features into one feature and assign new values to that one feature

Tags: python, pandas

```
fuel_type= {'fuel_Petrol':1,'fuel_Diesel':2,'fuel_Electric':3,'fuel_LPG':4,'fuel_CNG':5}
df['fueltype']= df['fuel_Petrol','fuel_Diesel','fuel_Electric','fuel_LPG','fuel_CNG'].apply(lamda x: fuel_type(x))
```

I am getting this error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-31-b238d0a16f2d>", line 2
    df['fueltype']= df['fuel_Petrol','fuel_Diesel','fuel_Electric','fuel_LPG','fuel_CNG'].apply(lamda x: fuel_type(x))
                                                                                                      ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a column with values which you would like to encode using a dictionary you should use:

```
fuel_type= {
    'fuel_Petrol':1,'fuel_Diesel':2,
    'fuel_Electric':3,'fuel_LPG':4,'fuel_CNG':5}

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'fuel_type': ['fuel_Petrol','fuel_Diesel',
                  'fuel_Electric','fuel_LPG','fuel_CNG']
})

df['fueltype'] = df['fuel_type'].apply(lambda  x: fuel_type[x])

print (df)
```

Output:

```
       fuel_type  fueltype
0    fuel_Petrol         1
1    fuel_Diesel         2
2  fuel_Electric         3
3       fuel_LPG         4
4       fuel_CNG         5
```

However, this is not a recommended methods when you have too many distinct values to encode. Rather use below way to encode which does not need us to create a dictionary manually.

```
df["fuel_type"] = df["fuel_type"].astype('category')
df["fueltype"] = df["fuel_type"].cat.codes
print (df)
```

Ouput:

```
       fuel_type  fueltype
0    fuel_Petrol         4
1    fuel_Diesel         1
2  fuel_Electric         2
3       fuel_LPG         3
4       fuel_CNG         0
```

sklearn also has functions to do the label encoding.